# How can I revert a tree selection (XamDataTree) when using Prism and the request is cancelled via ConfirmNavigationRequest?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have a `XamDataTree` that serves as a list of views that users can navigate to. Some views allow for user interaction and when the form is dirty I cancel any navigation commands (i.e. `XamDataTree` node change) via `IConfirmNavigationRequest`.  While navigation requests are cancelled the tree looks as though the navigation changed.  What is the best way to "undo" the tree selection when a navigation event has been cancelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean, but if you just want to unselect the tree node just set the SelectedItem to null.

EDIT: One approach would be to use the navigationCallback to determine what the result of the navigation was.

`_regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.ContentRegion, navigationPath, (e) =>
                {
                    var test = e.Result;
                });`

If it is false, then reset the selected tree node. You might have to do a check for the last navigated path so that you don't actually navigate again.

Comment: Hi Brian - hope you are doing well.  The issue I'm having is I have a tree control (XamDataTree) which is used for navigation.  User selects "Node A" which results in "View A" to be displayed in the content region.  User updates data and before saving clicks on "Node B".  "View Model A" knows nothing about the tree so am wondering if there is a lifecycle event that the tree can listen for and simply undo it's selection since the navigation was cancelled (via IConfirmNavigationRequest).  Example repo can be found at https://github.com/gvdonovan/RQWorkspace.

Comment: Thanks for the sample, it really helps understand what you were trying to do.  See my updated answer.